# A problem on solving functional equations

Tags: functional-equations

If $f(x),\forall x\in\mathbb{R}$ is continous and differentiable, and satisfies:

1. $f(x_1+x_2)+f(x_1-x_2)=2f(x_1)f(x_2),\forall x_1,x_2\in\mathbb{R}$
2. $f\left(1\right)=\dfrac{3}{2}$

How to prove:

$$f(x)=2^{-x-1} \left(\left(3-\sqrt{5}\right)^x+\left(3+\sqrt{5}\right)^x\right)$$

Is this the unique solution to $f(x)$?
Can we remove the `continous and differentiable` requirement for $f(x)$ in order to prove the uniqueness of the solution?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

> Not a solution but some observations:

With the substitution

$$\begin{aligned}
u &=x_1 + x_2 \\
t &= x_1 - x_2
\end{aligned}$$

we can write

$$f(u) + f(t) = 2 f\left(\frac{u+t}{2}\right) f\left(\frac{u-t}{2}\right)$$

For $u = t = 1$ we get

$$2f(1) = 2f(1)f(0)$$

which leads to

$$f(0) = 1$$

Setting either $u$ or $t$ to $1$ and the other variable to $x$ gives us:

$$\begin{aligned}
f(x) + \frac{3}{2} &= 2 f\left(\frac{x+1}{2}\right) f\left(\frac{x-1}{2}\right) \\
f(x) + \frac{3}{2} &= 2 f\left(\frac{x+1}{2}\right) f\left(\frac{1-x}{2}\right) 
\end{aligned}$$

This can be transformed to:

$$f\left(\frac{x-1}{2}\right) = f\left(\frac{1-x}{2}\right)$$

which is equivalent to the symmetry:

$$f(x) = f(-x)$$

$f(x)$ can never be $0$. (How to prove that?) Therefore, it must be positive for all $x$.